# En l'amitié ou en amitié

Tags: prépositions, articles

As far as I've learned so far, after certain prepositions (including en) the article is usually dropped. With that in mind, here, for this case in the subject, which one is true? Are both acceptable?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are possible but not interchangeable; e.g.:

> Croyez-vous en l'amitié homme-femme ?
>
> Il est fidèle en amitié.